# Bootstrap open tab form url and also support sub tabs

Tags: jquery, url, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs, show

I have this method used for opening bootstrap 3 tabs in my pages based on the url

myurl.com#tab1 ( opens #tab1 )

This is the code:

```
$(function () {
    var hash    = window.location.hash;
    hash && $('ul.nav a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

Im struggling to make this work for sub tabs also, Basically the idea is to have the url hash have more than one element like so:

myurl.com#top_tab1#sub_tab1

then:

1. Split the url hash so we can set a var top = #top_tab1
2. Split the url hash so we can set a var sub = #sub_tab1
3. Then be able to set both the top and sub tabs from url

Anyone can point me in right direction? I already tried the split method but fail to split correctly the hash somehow.

```
    var hash_split = hash.split('#');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var hashs = window.location.hash.match(/(\#[^#]+)/g)

["#top_tab1", "#sub_tab1"]

hashs[0];
hashs[1];
```

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more? Tried this regex and others but it just returns empty value if assigned to var split = .. your code

Comment: it will give you an array.
var hashs = window.location.hash.match(/(\#[^#]+)/g);
hashs[0];
hashs[1];